# Create an audio cable with 100k ohm resistors

Tags: audio, resistance

Please keep in mind I am a beginner.  Hopefully my terminology is correct.

I've purchased a new product called a [Mighty](https://bemighty.com/), which is sort of like an iPod but it streams music.  It works great with a set of headphones, but I tried plugging it into my car's Aux input and nothing came out.  Doing a little research, I discovered that there is something with the impedance of the output jack.  it requires an aux cable with an impedance less than 300, which apparently a headphone provides but a stereo extension cable that you would plug into an Aux jack in a car does not.

Is it possible to add 100k ohm resistors to a standard Aux cable?  I'm trying to find a pic or diagram online on how to do this as it seems like something a beginner can accomplish, but I can't find one.  or am I totally wrong in thinking this would work?

Comment: A series resistor or attenuator is possible, yes, but 100K is far, far too large.   However, your issue is probably not an impedance mismatch, but rather simply wrong wiring or mode selection - if it were a mismatch you'd probably hear at least distorted audio.

Answer (score 2):

From their [FAQ](https://bemighty.com/pages/faq-and-return-policy):

> **Can't hear music when using Mighty with an auxiliary cord / Does Mighty support AUX cord?**
>
> Mighty doesn't currently work with every type of auxiliary cord (which certain Bose headphones act as). The root cause is somewhat technical - it has to do with Mighty's headphone jack and the requirement to detect the aux cord plugin electronically. The good news is that this can be resolved through a software update and our tech team is currently working on this feature. We plan to roll out in the next month. [No date for the post, of course. It's a rolling month or "real soon now".]

You might be able to fool it by wiring a couple of hundred ohms between each signal wire and ground. I couldn't find any reference to 300 Ω you mentioned.

Comment: Good to see they're at least addressing my issue after a dozen or so emails.  :)  I guess I'll wait for the update to come out.  If not, do you know of any online resources for the wiring?  Is it as simple as inserting the resistor into the wire for each wire and ground, or do I have to cross any wires?

Comment: The resistors are to mimic the resistance of the headphone speakers that will be missing from your setup. The speakers are connected between each signal wire and the common. Time for you to do some web searching on headphone wiring ... How did you get this far in life without this knowledge? ;^)